# Multi-GPU Compatibility

Tags: computer-building, dual-gpu

I was just wondering... if I was only able to afford a $50 GPU or so, could I disconnect that $50 GPU and connect like an RX580 back into the PC without killing anything? (Once I could afford it, I'd probably buy 2 Sapphire Radeon RX580s)

EDIT: I already found a motherboard for the Crossfire-2 thingy. I'm just wondering if I could switch out the GPU once I get better ones...

Comment: if you mean "as long as I shut down the computer before doing it, can I upgrade components later on?", then the answer is absolutely yes! They slot into a port that they can easily be removed from

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer

Answer (score 0):

Yup! People often upgrade hardware, and graphics cards are one of the most common items to be upgraded. Most all graphics cards these days use a pci-e x16 connector (the bottom one in the image).

The one limitation is power draw. Modern cards are powered by a second connector from the power supply. If your new card is significantly more powerful, your power supply might not be capable of powering it. Of course, if this is the case, you can simply upgrade your power supply too.

[image]

Comment: Quick question: (I think this is a stupid question but I've never built a PC) I can also upgrade my RAM too right? Since the motherboard I want can have up to like 64GB with 4 slots I'd want to get like 8GB at first and then upgrade to like 32GB

Comment: 1) Make sure your motherboard has the right # of slots and check the max ammount of memory supported
2) make sure the 8GB and 32GB sticks are the same type (ex: DDR-4). Also make sure your motherboard supports that type of ram.  As long as all of that checks out, then you're good to go!